# How do I iterate over rows in a dataframe to detect different words and save it in a new column?

Tags: r, tags, stringr

I have been trying to write a function or use the apply family to select the rows in a data frame that contain the words I'm looking for and mark them like a tag. A row can have several tags. Can someone please help me, I have been stuck for a while.

If my question is unclear or if there is an answer somewhere else please guide me in the right direction. Much appreciated!

```
require(stringr)
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(sentences, rnorm(length(sentences)))

old = df %>% filter(str_detect(sentences, 'old')) %>% mutate(w = factor("old"))
new = df %>% filter(str_detect(sentences, 'new')) %>% mutate(w = factor("new"))
boy = df %>% filter(str_detect(sentences, 'boy')) %>% mutate(w = factor("boy"))
girl = df %>% filter(str_detect(sentences, 'girl')) %>% mutate(w = factor("girl"))
tags <- bind_rows(old, new, boy, girl)
```

So i want to choose a finite number of words for example:

```
tags <- c('bananas', 'apples', oranges)
```

And I want the result to be a data.frame with new columns for every word I have chosen. If the row contains one of the words I have chosen, the column for that words should be TRUE och marked somehow. Something like

```
Sentences     bananas     apples     oranges  
sentence1     TRUE        
sentence2                 TRUE
sentence3     TRUE
sentence4                            TRUE
sentence5                 TRUE       TRUE
```

or

```
Sentences     tag1        tag2
sentence1     bananas        
sentence2     apples
sentence3     bananas
sentence4     oranges
entences5     apples      oranges
```

Or something like that. Please let me know if I can explain more clearly.

Comment: What is the final solution you are looking for? Conceptually, what would it be able to do?

Comment: Is there a finite, known amount of words you are trying to tag?

Comment: I tried to explain a bit more, the number of words are finite yes and I want every row to be tagged if it contains any of the words. I don't know what might be good, either a column for every word or tag #1 #2 #3 up to the max(nr of tags).

Comment: Can you provide `sentences`?

Answer (score 0):

**Do you really want to use the apply function?** I'm pretty sure the `tm` package is what you're looking for. This is **the easiest and more robust way**. With the `DocumentTermMatrix` function you can get what you want. I have elaborated some sentences on my own (with a high syntactic level). The easiest way is to proceed with all the words and **once you have the matrix select those columns of the words you want to find**.

```
sentence1 <- "This is a bananana"
sentence2 <- "This is an apple"
sentence3 <- "This is a watermelon and a banana"
sentence4 <- "This is a watermelon a banana an apple"

df_sentence <- rbind(sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4)

library(tm)
vs_sentence <- VectorSource(df_sentence)
vc_sentence <- VCorpus(vs_sentence)

clean_sentence <- tm_map(vc_sentence, removePunctuation)
dtm_sentence <- DocumentTermMatrix(clean_sentence)
as.matrix(dtm_sentence)
```

The result:

```
        Terms
Docs and apple banana this watermelon
   1   0     0      1    1          0
   2   0     1      0    1          0
   3   1     0      1    1          1
   4   0     1      1    1          1
```

Also **there is another function** that allows you to obtain documents by columns and terms by rows:

```
as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(clean_sentence))
            Docs
Terms        1 2 3 4
  and        0 0 1 0
  apple      0 1 0 1
  banana     1 0 1 1
  this       1 1 1 1
  watermelon 0 0 1 1
```

If you could **provide a part of your sentences maybe it would be easier** to give you a better solution.
HTH!